# Is this an SQL Injection attack +and+(5=5+xor+2=9)--+a

Tags: sql, security

Is the following some sort of SQL injection attack? Checking log files today, I have noticed numerous entries such as these:

```
lat=52.350&lon=4.917"+and+(5=5+xor+2=9)--+a
lat=52.350&lon=4.917"+and+(1=1+xor+2=2)--+a
lat=52.350&lon=4.917"+and+not+1=7--+a
```

There are more, but I have added just the ones above. I'm not sure what they are trying to do.

Any insight would be helpful.

An example of a full URL is

```
http://www.example.com/5-Day-Weather-Forcast-For-Amsterdam?lat=52.350&lon=4.917"+and+(5=5+xor+2=9)--+a
```

This is the error they receive:

> The value 52.350 or 4.917" and (5=5 xor 2=9)-- a for your Latitude, Longitude is not in the correct format

Comment: Googling it shows websites whose popular search results include similar strings. i.e., `good sister' and (4=4 xor 9=15)-- a`

Comment: Looks like some randomly generated attack. Why else would anyone write 2=9 instead of 0=1? Maybe this is supposed to evade automatic SQL attack detection heuristics.

Comment: No. It might be a harebrained guess that the site owners are doing eval("") or system("bc %1") on any and all arguments.

Comment: Perhaps the idea is to use non-trivial expressions some of which will evaluate to true and others to false; if all the true expressions return results and all the false return none, then the SQL injection succeeded, and the site can be addedto a list of targets for further investigation.

Comment: Hi @remyabel I saw the same when googling this before posting question

Comment: As I use var gc   = new GeoCoordinate();
var validateLatitude = gc.Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
var validateLongitude   = gc.Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(lon); and catch any FormatExceptions, I think they will not get passed my 1st layer of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely yes.

A standard approach to testing for [boolean-based blind SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)#Boolean_Exploitation_Technique) is to attempt to identify a parameter that will accept additional clauses and produce reliably different responses when the clauses evaluate to true or false.

If adding " `and 1=1` " to a query gives the same results, but " `and 1=2` " gives an error or different results, then it's reasonable to infer that the additional SQL is being parsed.

SQL injection and web application scanning tools will typically try multiple variations of these boolean test payloads using different combinations parentheses and quotes to attempt to fit into the syntax of the vulnerable query. If you're interested in this, hooking up a tool like [SQLmap](http://sqlmap.org/) to run through a proxy and watching it attempt to find a vulnerable parameter is like a master class in SQLi.